# Use C++ and FFmpeg to stream to Flash Media Server

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, flash-media-server

I'm building an application in C++ that should use FFmpeg to send a live stream to Flash Media Server. For starters I would like to be able to send a .mp4 file. Using the FFmpeg .exe I can do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i TEST.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://[host]/[application]/[stream]
```

How would you go about implementing something like that in code? I can only figure out how to read data, not write it. I have found functions to open input but nothing about how to connect to FMS. All write functions I can find seems to be how to write to file. Please advice.

Comment: strange question. There's `ffplay.c`. Use the source Luke, may the force be with you.

Comment: But as far as I understand ffplay is a player and I need to send data not read it. Also, why is it a strange question?

Comment: `ffmpeg` has a tradition of terse or non-existent docs. The main reference are the sources.

Comment: I understand that much :) But even after looking through the source I can only find examples on reading from a stream and I need to send data to FMS.

Comment: You need to look into `ffmpeg.c` itself then. An extreme solution is to compile the entire `ffmpeg.c` into your application and send it command line parameters (after renaming `main()`).